# Can I have dependent pick lists in design attributes

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-components, design-attributes

I'm working on a case where I want to show picklists in design attributes. Here, in my case, I want to show them dynamically. i.e. let us take that there 2 picklists in design attributes, first to select parent and the second to select child element. When I select **Account** in first picklist, the second picklist should show only the object names having lookup to **Account**. I was trying out code, but my code is limited only to the current picklist, is there a way that I can have dependent picklists?

Here is my code.

```
global class MyCustomPickList extends VisualEditor.DynamicPickList {
  global override VisualEditor.DataRow getDefaultValue() {
    VisualEditor.DataRow defaultValue = new VisualEditor.DataRow('account', ' Account');
    return defaultValue;
  }

  global override VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows getValues() {
    VisualEditor.DataRow value1 = new VisualEditor.DataRow('account', 'Account');
    VisualEditor.DataRow value2 = new VisualEditor.DataRow('contact', 'Contact');
    VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows myValues = new VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows();
    myValues.addRow(value1);
    myValues.addRow(value2);
    return myValues;
  }
}
```

Please let me know how I achieve this dynamic dependent design attributes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. You'll want to vote on this [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CTa2QAG).